# Starting python code with raw_input on boot automatically on raspberry

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

i'm currently working with rfid usb reader, this is a cheap rfid usb reader that work just like keyboard, when you tap a card to it, it will type the code of card in the window that opened, just like keyboard.

When i try it using LXTerminal, it works perfectly as i want it to be, but when i try to automatically use it on boot up and as startup program in rclocal, it won't work because the raw_input doesn't get any input from the usb rfid reader. I think it because the usb reader is typing the code not in the same window with the python program that i have made.

```
import time

data=["0000011122","002219292"]

while 1 :
    text=raw_input()
    if text in data:
        print(ok)
    else:
        print(nope)
```

so, how to make the rfid usb reader write the code to my python code on startup?

Comment: Please check if [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/55431/read-keyboad-input-from-background-process) helps you.